# change speed of tab selection

Tags: application-development, desktop-environments

I am wondering if it's possible to change the speed at which selection of buttons, links, etc...moves, when 'tab' is pressed (in many applications)

is it system wide? or application dependent?

thanks

Comment: Hello. What version of Ubuntu and please give an example of an application.

Comment: The system tries to do that "as fast as possible". You cannot change that speed.

Comment: hi @David browser for instance (I am on brave)  -- I am on dual boot, last mint and last ubuntu LTS